# Whats the maximum size of Virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I am new to the concept of virtual memory.
I will like to know whats the maximum space of memory a procces can use through virtual memory?
Is it available RAM + available swap space ??

(This question has already been asked but people had different opinions on this issue)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OPERATING SYSTEMS: what is the size of the virtual memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392218/operating-systems-what-is-the-size-of-the-virtual-memory)

Comment: so the maximum size a process can get is obviously less than ram + hard disk size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most systems the maximum size of virtual memory is determined by the number of bits in a virtual address that are supported by the MMU.

For example; for typical 64-bit 80x86 CPUs a virtual address is 64 bits, but only the lowest 48 bits are supported by the MMU, so the virtual address size is `1 << 48 = 256 TiB`. Everything else (amount of RAM, swap space, etc) doesn't matter.

In theory, you can (e.g.) fill the entire virtual address space by mapping the same page of RAM everywhere; and (for 64-bit 80x86) it would only cost 4 KiB of RAM (for the data that's mapped everywhere) plus another 16 KiB of RAM (for MMU's own data - page tables, etc). In other words, a measly 20 KiB of physical RAM is enough to fill a whopping 256 TiB of virtual space.

Of course for practical purposes often the kernel reserves some of the virtual address space (e.g. half of it), so a process can only use the remainder (e.g. 128 TiB); and (for modern 64-bit CPUs) unless you're mapping the same data at different places in the virtual address space (which would be silly/pointless) it's likely that you'll run out of things to put in a virtual address space before you run out of virtual address space.

This isn't the case for older 32-bit CPUs, where the virtual address space is a lot smaller (where maybe a process can only use 2 GiB out of a 4 GiB total space) and it's a lot easier to run out of space.

Comment: `the maximum size of virtual memory is determined by the number of bits in a virtual address` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609035/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27937318/11683?