# How does an OS such as Linux load executables into virtual memory?

Tags: x86, operating-system, paging, loader, virtual-memory

I have read this statement from this link:

[Executable Object Files and Virtual Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492168/executable-object-files-and-virtual-memory)

> When an executable file is started, the OS (kernel) creates a virtual address space and an (initially empty) process, and examines the executable file's header.

But I don't understand how does `examines the executable file's header` happen?

Shoudn't the binary be loaded in memory to begin with, before the OS can examine the executable file's header? CPU can't run instructions directly on HDD.

I'm guessing the Loader should be able to see the addresses allocated to the binary during compilation and map them to the newly created virtual memory.

Also in case the binary is loaded by the OS, doe sit get loaded entirely? or it does lazy loading and loads pages as needed afterwords. How much would it load initially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shoudn't the binary be loaded in memory to begin with, before the OS can examine the executable file's header?

Well, only the *header* of the binary has to be loaded into memory for this step.  The kernel loads the header and inspects it to see how to set up mappings for the various sections of the binary.  The header might say, for instance, "map bytes 4096-65535 of the binary into memory at address 0x12345000, read-only and executable"; "map 16384 bytes of zero-initialized memory at address 0xdeadf000, read-write", and so on.  After these mappings are set up, the kernel doesn't need to keep the binary's header in memory anymore, and can free that space.

> Also in case the binary is loaded by the OS, does it get loaded entirely?

No.

> or it does lazy loading and loads pages as needed afterwards.

Yes.

> How much would it load initially?

Potentially none at all. It can rely instead on the page fault handler to do it when the process actually accesses the memory.  In that case, the `sysret`, or whatever instruction the kernel uses to transfer control to the program's entry point, would itself cause a page fault, at which point the page containing the first instruction at the entry point would be loaded from the binary as specified by the mapping for that address.  When the fault handler returned, that first instruction would be in memory and would be executed.  As the process executes more instructions touching more memory, more and more of its pages  will be loaded.

The kernel could, as an optimization, *prefault* some of these pages into memory, based on guesses as to which ones are likely to be accessed in the near future.  I don't know exactly to what extent this is done.

Comment: Linux for example does load (into pagecache) and prefault (wire the page into the HW page tables) at least the entry point before trying to enter user-space.  IDK how much if any more pages are queued up to get loaded, or get wired if already available.