# How Paging Saves External Fragmentation

Tags: operating-system

What is the pages in operating system and how paging saves in the External fragmentation please explain in detail.

Comment: Go through standard books before asking here. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658791/how-does-external-fragmentation-happen.