# What explains the term orthogonal in a more non-nerd fashion?

Tags: terminology, orthogonal

For example:

> Cardinality and optionality are
>   orthogonal properties of a
>   relationship. You can specify that a
>   relationship is optional, even if you
>   have specified upper and/or lower
>   bounds. This means that there do not
>   have to be any objects at the
>   destination, but if there are then the
>   number of objects must lie within the
>   bounds specified.

What exactly does "orthogonal" mean? I bet it's just a fancy soundig nerd-style word for something that could be expressed a lot easier to understand for average people ;)

From wikipedia:

> In mathematics, two vectors are
>   orthogonal if they are perpendicular,
>   i.e., they form a right angle. The
>   word comes from the Greek ὀρθός
>   (orthos), meaning "straight", and
>   γωνία (gonia), meaning "angle".

Anyone?

Comment: I often find a dictionary helpful in these cases.... http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthogonal :)

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527393/what-is-orthogonality/1527443#1527443

Comment: Dictionaries are good, but they fail at explaining this one clearly, in this context ;) I mean... like 500 words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the quoted context above you could substitute the word "independent" or "unrelated" for "orthogonal".

Comment: unrelated / independent. Perfect!! Why not in the first place, the simple way...thought Apple is going for massive simplification of all things ;) ...remembers me about a age old star trek movie where someone farted and the doctor told him something in latin with 20 words. after a long discussion it turned out that what the doctor wanted to say was simply that the patient experienced flatulence (a kind of force that makes you fart, all the time).

Comment: It's just human nature - when people learn a new word they look for opportunities to use it. In this particular case it's not really appropriate, since simpler words will suffice.

Comment: @dontWatchMyProfile - in answer to your question, it's just a way of constraining the number of people who they consider to be "in their club". you can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitism

Answer (score 4):

Items/concepts/values etc.. that are Orthogonal means that one does not constrain the other, so you can establish one item/concept/value without regards for how other orthogonal items are set.

Loosely speaking, orthogonal means independent.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in 2d space an orthogonal line is one with bends at 90 degrees to each other.