# Library design - Eliminating dom dependencies

Tags: php, javascript

```
<div id='universals' data-path='/a/' data-load='1'></div>
```

This is a realy odd case.  I have front-end code ( JavaScript ) which knows where it's resources are based upon a path I pass to it via PHP which writes the HTML above.

This is a cool feature that allows me to simply rename the root of my folder on the server and everything keeps working as PHP determines the current working directory and sends it to the client via the code above.

It is a form of reflection.

However I want to build this into an application framework on the front-end.

Now my javascript library, let's call it foo.js is dependent upon a dom element.  I'm pretty sure this is not good practice.

My plan it to just make the id settable like this.

```
foo.setUniverisal('#universal');
```

and then put in the documentation which attributes are needed.

Any other ideas or better ways to eliminate any kind of dom dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is the simplest one:

```
foo.setDataPath("pathToData")
```

Then your client-side "glue" code (one that puts together your library, HTML and PHP) will take a path from your tag and call foo.setDataPath. This will be the most orthogonal design ([What is "Orthogonality"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527393/what-is-orthogonality)).

Example of situation, where it might be relevant: what if this libary be initialized from the HTML, where this tag cannot be generated. For example, because HTML will be served statically (or via CDN).

Comment: ...I'll just set a default for those who do not use that feature.